# profile-report doesn't show any report data

Tags: profiler

I used `M-x profiler-start RET RET` then after a few other operations I did `M-x profiler-stop`.

Then `M-x profiler-report`. It doesn't show any profile data.

I am using OSX.  Where is profile data supposed to be saved? and what is the file name supposed to be?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `M-x profiler-report` *before* you do `M-x profilter-stop`.  The profiling data is not saved in any file, it's kept in memory.